# How do I change the icon of a simple dialog in tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, simpledialog

Not sure how to change the icon of a simple dialog window. I try to use .bitmap but doesn't work. Need Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `default` keyword argument to the `iconbitmap()` for the icon of the root, then all the child windows will inherit the icon.

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.iconbitmap(default="C:\\Users\\username\\random.ico")

dialog = simpledialog.askstring("INFO", "wut ur name?")

root.mainloop()
```

Result with `default`:

[image]

Results without `default`:
[image]

Comment: This works while running the script. But once you compile with pyinstaller, icons do not show. You have to remove the `default` keyword for the icons to show in the compiled exe.  Then this issue with `simpledialog` remains.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
from tkinter import Tk
master = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "Any image file")
master.iconphoto(False, photo)
```